# Calcular dias entre 2 fechas sin contar los feriados ni fines de semana - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme a contar los dias entre 2 fechas sin contar los feriados(cargados en mi bdd) y sin contar sabados-domingos. Ejemplo: hoy ( Lunes 26-04-2021 al Viernes 30-04-2021 ) hay 4 dias habiles, pero supongamos que en mi registro tengo cargado un feriado (miercoles 28-04-2021) los dias habiles serian 3 en vez de 4. En el codigo siguiente lo que hace es sacar la cantidad de dias entre 2 fechas, y lo que esta en modo comentario es como obtener los feriados de la bdd. Ahora faltaria conseguir lo otro.

```
    // $date = Noworkingday::all('id', 'startdate');
    $fechainicial= new DateTime("2021-04-01");    
    $fechafinal= new DateTime("2021-05-04");

    $diff = $fechainicial->diff($fechafinal);

        echo $diff->days . ' dias';
```

Acá dejo la tabla donde estan los registros(feriados)

```
Schema::create('configinstitucional_noworkingdays', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
  
            $table->string('title',200);
            $table->datetime('startdate');
            $table->datetime('enddate');
            $table->longText('description')->nullable();
            
            $table->boolean('status')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

Comment: Podrías ir recorriendo los días desde la `$fechainicial` hasta `$fechafinal`, controlando si es fin de semana o si existen un feriado para la fecha. PD: deberías devolver solo los feriados que existen en ese rango de fechs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo la siguiente función que calcula los días transcurridos, entre la fecha de inicio y la fecha final, y no toma en cuenta sábados y domingos, al igual que puedes agregar los días feriados. Espero te funcione.

```
public function daysWeek($inicio, $fin){
    
            $start = new DateTime($inicio);
            $end = new DateTime($fin);

            //de lo contrario, se excluye la fecha de finalización (¿error?)
            $end->modify('+1 day');
    
            $interval = $end->diff($start);
    
            // total dias
            $days = $interval->days;
    
            // crea un período de fecha iterable (P1D equivale a 1 día)
            $period = new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);
    
            // almacenado como matriz, por lo que puede agregar más de una fecha feriada
            $holidays = array('2012-09-07');
    
            foreach($period as $dt) {
                $curr = $dt->format('D');

                // obtiene si es Sábado o Domingo
                if($curr == 'Sat' || $curr == 'Sun') {
                    $days--;
                }elseif (in_array($dt->format('Y-m-d'), $holidays)) {
                    $days--;
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Por mi parte dejo esta solucion a la cual pude llegar, espero y les sirva.

```
static public function prueba($startsAt = '2021-04-20', $endsAt = '2021-04-30')
    {
        if ($startsAt === null) {
            $fechainicial = new DateTime(strtotime("today"));
        } else {
            $fechainicial = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $startsAt);
        }
        if ($endsAt === null) {
            $fechafinal = new DateTime(strtotime("today"));
        } else {
            $fechafinal = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $endsAt);
        }
        //dias habiles entre 2 fechas
        $diferenciaendias = $fechafinal->diff($fechainicial);
        

        $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
        $daterange = new DatePeriod($fechainicial, $interval ,$fechafinal);

        //obtengo los feriados de la bdd (solo tengo 2 registros como prueba)
        $feriados = Noworkingday::whereBetween('startdate', [$fechainicial->format('Y-m-d'), $fechafinal->format('Y-m-d')])->get();
        
        $feriados = $feriados->reject(function($feriado){
            return $feriado->startdate->isWeekend();
        });
        $feriados->count();

        $diasHabiles = 0;

        //saco los fines de semana y los feriados (totala sacar = 4)
        foreach($daterange as $date){
            if ($date->format("N") === '6' OR $date->format("N") === '7') {
                continue;
            } 
            $diasHabiles++;
        }
        return 'Días sin contar feriados ni fines de semanas'.($diasHabiles - $feriados->count()). 'Dias Hábiles'.$diferenciaendias->days;
    }
```